# How long would a victim of murder be kept by the police before burial?

Tags: government

In my story, a man has been killed by being shot twice in New York City; once in the shoulder, once in the chest. The police believe that they know who killed the man, but they are not entirely certain and do not have any incriminating evidence. How long would they likely hang onto the body for investigation purposes before allowing the family to bury it?

Comment: Depends on the country, and probably the locality within the country.

Comment: Why not allow the funeral to proceed? Normally the police take the body to the morgue, an autopsy is performed by the pathologist, all the evidence is collected and recorded, then the body is released to a funeral home. There is no reason to keep the body around. It's not as if there is one kind of funeral service for murder victimes whose the killer has been convicted, and another for those whose killer is still at large. If, in *very* exceptional cases, the body needs to be re-examined then an exhumation order can be issued by a judge.

Comment: @AlexP: Except that a buried body will have decayed somewhat.  I have it on good authority - that is, I've read a fair number of murder mysteries :-) - that the police &c do sometimes require a body to be kept unburied (and presumably in cold storage &c) for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state (in the US) has broad powers to retain the body for official purposes including criminal investigation. Weeks-to-months is not unheard of if there are special circumstances. They'd keep it for some short period after they were done so that it could be claimed, but otherwise it'd be cremated. Ashes are kept for years sometimes before being claimed. NYC used to bury in a potter's field for unclaimed, but I think that changed awhile back.

The reasons for keeping a body for an unusual amount of time could include uncommon toxicological tests, bringing in expert pathologists to run an autopsy, or high profile criminal cases (a serial killer may be responsible and the press is going wild). Depending on the length of time they've held the body, family might or might not succeed in getting a judge to sign off on a court order (injunction, I think?) to release it for the funeral. But not everyone can afford that, and the more unusual the circumstances, the more leeway they'd be willing to grant authorities.

For comparison purposes, a more typical duration would be 1-2 weeks max, but more likely just 2-5 days depending on when it fell within the business week.